# Casting value before applying conditional

Tags: google-sheets

I want to summarize values by the condition of the month of date data.
I use “dd mmm yyyy” format, an example “12 Aug 2021”

Google sheet is typecasting text entry to date value. However, when add text based condition, it does not recognize since it is handled as date.

Here what I have tried so far:
`=sumif(A2:A,"Aug",D2:D)`
`=sumif(B2:B,"*Aug*",D2:D)`
`=sumif($C$2:$C,"=8",$D$2:$D)`
`sumif($A$2:$A,"="&date(2021,8,30),$D$2:$D)`

I can simply use helper columns to cast date to text, or extract month as integer, but I am seeking a more low coupling solution to eliminate the extra column.

I wonder whether it is possible to apply casting on iteration unit before testing conditional? Or any other possible solution that I am not aware of except for using scripts.

**Example Sheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A7fCHHOlUTxflN9DmHVpSgpWTwDG8nojQrucOOGgsGA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=sumif(arrayformula(month(A2:A)),8,D2:D)
```

for August